# Speeding up iterating over Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, gdal

I am working on performing image processing using Numpy, specifically a running standard deviation stretch.  This reads in X number of columns, finds the Std. and performs a percentage linear stretch.  It then iterates to the next "group" of columns and performs the same operations.  The input image is a 1GB, 32-bit, single band raster which is taking quite a long time to process (hours).  Below is the code.

I realize that I have 3 nested for loops which is, presumably where the bottleneck is occurring.  If I process the image in "boxes", that is to say loading an array that is [500,500] and iterating through the image processing time is quite short.  Unfortunately, camera error requires that I iterate in extremely long strips (52,000 x 4) (y,x) to avoid banding.

Any suggestions on speeding this up would be appreciated:

```
def box(dataset, outdataset, sampleSize, n):

    quiet = 0
    sample = sampleSize
    #iterate over all of the bands
    for j in xrange(1, dataset.RasterCount + 1): #1 based counter

        band = dataset.GetRasterBand(j)
        NDV = band.GetNoDataValue()

        print "Processing band: " + str(j)       

        #define the interval at which blocks are created
        intervalY = int(band.YSize/1)    
        intervalX = int(band.XSize/2000) #to be changed to sampleSize when working

        #iterate through the rows
        scanBlockCounter = 0

        for i in xrange(0,band.YSize,intervalY):

            #If the next i is going to fail due to the edge of the image/array
            if i + (intervalY*2) < band.YSize:
                numberRows = intervalY
            else:
                numberRows = band.YSize - i

            for h in xrange(0,band.XSize, intervalX):

                if h + (intervalX*2) < band.XSize:
                    numberColumns = intervalX
                else:
                    numberColumns = band.XSize - h

                scanBlock = band.ReadAsArray(h,i,numberColumns, numberRows).astype(numpy.float)

                standardDeviation = numpy.std(scanBlock)
                mean = numpy.mean(scanBlock)

                newMin = mean - (standardDeviation * n)
                newMax = mean + (standardDeviation * n)

                outputBlock = ((scanBlock - newMin)/(newMax-newMin))*255
                outRaster = outdataset.GetRasterBand(j).WriteArray(outputBlock,h,i)#array, xOffset, yOffset


                scanBlockCounter = scanBlockCounter + 1
                #print str(scanBlockCounter) + ": " + str(scanBlock.shape) + str(h)+ ", " + str(intervalX)
                if numberColumns == band.XSize - h:
                    break

                #update progress line
                if not quiet:
                    gdal.TermProgress_nocb( (float(h+1) / band.YSize) )
```

Here is an update:
Without using the profile module, as I did not want to start wrapping small sections of the code into functions I used a mix of print and exit statements to get a really rough idea about which lines were taking the most time.  Luckily (and I do understand how lucky I was) one line was dragging everything down.

```
    outRaster = outdataset.GetRasterBand(j).WriteArray(outputBlock,h,i)#array, xOffset, yOffset
```

It appears that GDAL is quite inefficient when opening the output file and writing out the array.  With this in mind I decided to add my modified arrays "outBlock" to a python list, then write out chunks.  Here is the segment that I changed:

The outputBlock was just modified ...

```
         #Add the array to a list (tuple)
            outputArrayList.append(outputBlock)

            #Check the interval counter and if it is "time" write out the array
            if len(outputArrayList) >= (intervalX * writeSize) or finisher == 1:

                #Convert the tuple to a numpy array.  Here we horizontally stack the tuple of arrays.
                stacked = numpy.hstack(outputArrayList)

                #Write out the array
                outRaster = outdataset.GetRasterBand(j).WriteArray(stacked,xOffset,i)#array, xOffset, yOffset
                xOffset = xOffset + (intervalX*(intervalX * writeSize))

                #Cleanup to conserve memory
                outputArrayList = list()
                stacked = None
                finisher=0
```

Finisher is simply a flag that handles the edges.  It took a bit of time to figure out how to build an array from the list.  In that, using numpy.array was creating a 3-d array (anyone care to explain why?) and write array requires a 2d array.  Total processing time is now varying from just under 2 minutes to 5 minutes.  Any idea why the range of times might exist?

Many thanks to everyone who posted!  The next step is to really get into Numpy and learn about vectorization for additional optimization.

Comment: Have you profiled to find out where your hot spots are?  I can imagine cases where you're limited by file IO and should pull data from disk in bigger chunks.  Likewise, you could be memory starved and should pay attention to creating unnecessary copies.  You could even be compute bound and should think about better algorithms.

Comment: Can you explain what type of object 'band' is? I agree with matt--you need to profile your code to determine which parts are slowing you down.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? 1GB isn't that big of an array. You should be able to just load the entire thing into memory on a modern machine. A contrast stretch like (I think?) you're wanting to do can be done in-place. (e.g. `data -= whatever` and `data /= whatever` will operate elementwise on the entire array without making a copy).

Comment: @Luke band is a SwigObject of type GDALRasterBandShadow. Basically R in an RGB image, although these are single band black and white.  @matt the bottleneck is occurring writing back to disk at "outraster ="  @Joe Kington I have 4GB and can load the entire image.  This is simply a test though as the program will process 50GB+ global mosaics.  That is why I am trying to avoid reading in the entire array.

Comment: If the bottleneck really is I/O, then you pretty much have no choice; optimizing the rest of the code won't help.

Comment: If you are IO bound, you should chunk your reads/writes.  Try dumping ~500 MB of data to an ndarray, process it all, write it out and then grab the next ~500 MB.  Make sure to reuse the ndarray.

Comment: @matt - I just got that implemented this morning.  Total processing time 1 minutes, 48 seconds!  I am loading the modified arrays into a list, stacking them using vstack or hstack (depending on direction) and then writing them out.  I think the problem is with how GDAL accesses and writes arrays.  If you post your comment as an answer I can check mark it.  I think that that is how things work around here?

Comment: @Jzl5325, in answer to your question about 3-d arrays, `numpy.array` infers the shape of an array from the structure of the data passed to it. If you pass it a list of lists, it infers a 2-d shape, and if you pass it a list of 2-d arrays, it infers a 3-d shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered as requested.

If you are IO bound, you should chunk your reads/writes. Try dumping ~500 MB of data to an ndarray, process it all, write it out and then grab the next ~500 MB. Make sure to reuse the ndarray.

Answer (score 7):

One way to speed up operations over `numpy` data is to use `vectorize`. Essentially, vectorize takes a function `f` and creates a new function `g` that maps `f` over an array `a`. `g` is then called like so: `g(a)`.

```
>>> sqrt_vec = numpy.vectorize(lambda x: x ** 0.5)
>>> sqrt_vec(numpy.arange(10))
array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.73205081,  2.        ,
        2.23606798,  2.44948974,  2.64575131,  2.82842712,  3.        ])
```

Without having the data you're working with available, I can't say for certain whether this will help, but perhaps you can rewrite the above as a set of functions that can be `vectorized`. Perhaps in this case you could vectorize over an array of indices into `ReadAsArray(h,i,numberColumns, numberRows)`. Here's an example of the potential benefit:

```
>>> print setup1
import numpy
sqrt_vec = numpy.vectorize(lambda x: x ** 0.5)
>>> print setup2
import numpy
def sqrt_vec(a):
    r = numpy.zeros(len(a))
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        r[i] = a[i] ** 0.5
    return r
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='a = sqrt_vec(numpy.arange(1000000))', setup=setup1, number=1)
0.30318188667297363
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='a = sqrt_vec(numpy.arange(1000000))', setup=setup2, number=1)
4.5400981903076172
```

A 15x speedup! Note also that numpy slicing handles the edges of `ndarray`s elegantly:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
>>> a[3:7, 3:7]
array([[18, 19],
       [23, 24]])
```

So if you could get your `ReadAsArray` data into an `ndarray` you wouldn't have to do any edge-checking shenanigans.

---

Regarding your question about reshaping -- reshaping doesn't fundamentally alter the data at all. It just changes the "strides" by which `numpy` indices the data. When you call the `reshape` method, the value returned is a new view into the data; the data isn't copied or altered at all, nor is the old view with the old stride information.

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(25)
>>> b = a.reshape((5, 5))
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> a[5]
5
>>> b[1][0]
5
>>> a[5] = 4792
>>> b[1][0]
4792
>>> a.strides
(8,)
>>> b.strides
(40, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am reading the vectorization documentation now and working on getting my code modified.  The readAsArray does return an ndarray.  The issue I am running in to is that the array can be larger than 3gb in size (these are huge images) and I need to segment them prior to ingesting them.  I believe that the bottleneck I am seeing is actually in the writing out of the new array block by block.  I am trying to write out to a Tuple and to reduce the number of writes.  Combined with vectorization and this might work!

Comment: One more question as I search about.  To handle edges well do I need to reshape?  I am hesitant to because I am dealing with satellite imagery and am trying to leverage the spatial autocorrelation when stretching the (essentially) albedo.

Comment: @Jzl5325, see my edit regarding reshaping. In short, reshaping doesn't change the data at all.

Comment: From the numpy docs: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html                                                                 In other words, it doesn't rely on optimized, precompiled C functions so there is no runtime advantage to be had

Comment: @Ender, it does not follow from the fact that `vectorize` is provided primarily for convenience that there is *no* runtime advantage to be had. Please take a second look at the test I included. There is an order-of-magnitude speedup. Of course, if you can use built-in numpy operations you might get a three-order-of-magnitude speedup. But if you can't, `vectorize` can still sometimes help a bit.

Comment: @senderle, yes this is an oversight on my part; my zeal in pointing this out stems from vectorize's somewhat misleading name. It may help others to note in the answer that vectorize doesn't actually call precompiled, optimized C code.

Comment: @Ender, the thing is, the routine actually does call a precompiled C for loop, as I suspected and have been able to confirm. Here is the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/ufunc.html#c.PyUFunc_On_Om) for the loop function that `vectorize` uses (via `umath.frompyfunc`, which it calls internally), and here is the [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/73fe877ff967f279d470b81ad447b9f3056c1335/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src#L321).

Comment: @Ender, of course the content of the function itself is not converted into C; it's merely called via the C API for generic Python functions. But that's still potentially a lot faster than using a Python for loop to do the same thing.

Comment: @senderle, I see. Thanks for pointing these things out and for going through the trouble of collecting the appropriate references. I've never really looked at numpy source so this was a cool foray into unexplored territory!

Answer (score 2):

Without trying to completely understand exactly what you are doing, I notice that you aren't using any [numpy slices](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c) or [array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-081b5e0ff3963e102f4bb39b39261750b507895e), both of which may speed up your code, or, at the very least, make it more readable. My apologies if these aren't germane to your problem.

Comment: I had thought about indexing.  From the documentation it looks like I would need to load the entire array into memory to do this?  Using band.ReadAsArray - a GDAL function.

Comment: Well. Try to rethink your problem and write it in as a matrix operation. If you can do it so, then you can easily apply this into python with numpy (your matrix would be a 2d-array and so on, ...). If you running into trouble with memory then try to do it in submatrices or other representations for matrices. Sorry, I can't help you more than this few hints. I couldn't really get into your snippet ;)